# Test tabbar badge via Xcode UI XCTests in iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, uitabbaritem, badge

How to check that tabbar badge (`tabBarItem.badgeValue`) contains correct number in `XCTests`?

[image]

I can see target tabbar button in Accessibility Inspector, but badge element isn't inspectable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the accessibilityIdentifier value to the tab bar item.

`tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "Your_Identifier"`

On your UITest case,

```
guard let value = app.buttons["Your_Identifier"].value as? String 
else {
    XCTFail("badge value not updated")
    return
}
XCTAssert(value == "1 item", "badge value not updated")
```

The value will be in the format "number_on_badge item(s)". Thus in your case, you should be testing against "19 items".

Comment: Thanks, works! By the way, is there a possibility to test badge number in app icon on home screen?

Comment: FYI the format is "[X] items" even when X == 1. Always plural.